# Can I turn off the automatic single instance feature in Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Windows Mobile 6 single instances applications by default can I turn off or override this behavior? This is needed if one needs to automatically restart or self update an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex Feinman describes how it works, and how to get around it, in [this blog post](http://blog.opennetcf.com/afeinman/PermaLink,guid,ec034858-e071-4daa-b1be-0323b7f54b11.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> This is needed if one needs to automatically restart or self update an application.

This doesn't answer your question, but instead of that I launch a separate restarter or updater process.